# "non-greedy" diff output?

Tags: diff

I want a diff output like

```
- old line 1
+ new line 1
- old line 2
+ new line 2
```

*instead* of

```
- old line 1
- old line 2
+ new line 1
+ new line 2
```

Is there a way to do this with GNU `diff` and/or other standard programs? `--inhibit-hunk-merge` looked promising, but it seems to be deprecated.

**Context:** I'm comparing two CSV files which differ only in a few columns. I want to

- Make sure no other columns are changed
- Compare the changed columns one by one (all rows are changed in those columns)

The plan is to

1. Transpose the two CSV files so `diff` can compare columns
2. `diff` and check each line in the output

I could use a side-by-side diff, but because each line is quite long, which contains every value for each row, that will be quite a strain on my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like:

```
diff -y file1 file2 | perl -n -pe 's/(.*)\|\t(.*)/- $1\n+ $2/'
```

Comment: Wow, how obvious! I still wonder why diff doesn't support line-by-line output, other than chunking it all together.